# When and why is "flied" used as the past tense of "fly"?

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Why is the form "flied" used in baseball instead of "flew"?

Comment: Notwithstanding the accuracy of the two answers below, the Oakland Athletics had an otherwise very competent radio play-by-play man a decade or so ago who insisted on saying things  like "He flew out to center field in the second [inning]." At the other end of the spectrum, I can imagine someone saying of a frog that had been catching flies all day and no longer seemed interested in them, "I guess he's flied out."

Answer (score 6):

The form "flied" is used in baseball because the verb *fly* in this case means *to hit a **fly ball***.

It is probably safe to assume that this usage is a transformation of the noun *fly ball* (also called a *fly*) into a verb, and noun→verb transformations such as this are often regularized

Answer (score 0):

The term is only useful in baseball in reference to a "fly-ball".

[This link has](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/fly-flew-has-flown-flied/):

> When the fly ball is caught by a member of the opposing team, and it is in bounds, the batter is out and the play is recorded as a “fly out.” The batter can then be said to have **flied** out.