# Is "hangman" a gender neutral term?

Tags: single-word-requests, gender-neutral

And if not, is there an adequate gender-neutral term that isn't 'executioner'? I'm studying the poem "The Hangman" by Maurice Ogden, the opening line of which is "Into the town, the Hangman came." The word has loaded connotations, so I'm wondering if there's any suitable replacement.

Comment: If the title is *hangman* there is little you can do to avoid mentioning by its name. Why would you replace it? I have never heard *hangman* accused of being sexist, this is a first for me.

Comment: I would suppose it comes from a time when all those who did the hanging were men. I can't recall knowing of a hang woman. So from my view it is likely to be an accurate term, but isn't meant to be sexist in any way. Executioner would be the alternative.

Comment: Do you know anyone who might make a good hangwoman? In the 1950s when the medieval practice of capital punishment was still in place in Britain, there was only one woman, of whom I'm aware who was hanged, namely Ruth Ellis. Have you read the poem 'Ballad of Reading Jail' by Oscar Wilde?

Comment: The gender-neutral term would be _hangperson_. There is a great gender disparity in the hangperson profession. Girls at school need to be encouraged to become hangpersons.

Comment: Why do you need a gender-neutral term?  I'm pretty sure you'll find that there have never been any female professional execution-by-noose practitioners and thus no need for the word to exist.

Comment: @WS2 Ruth Ellis was only the _last_ woman hanged in Britain. [This page lists 41](http://www.capitalpunishmentuk.org/femhang.html) between 1868 and 1955.

Comment: Back when I was a kid and played *Hangman* with individuals of the female gender I don't recall that there was any restriction regarding how they played the game vs how boys did it.

Comment: The UK's Pierrepoint family (Albert + siblings/nephews of the paternal line) held the dubious distinction of being the Kingdom's official hangman/hangmen. There should still be a family female out there who could be called upon to officiate at a judicial hanging as the gibbet still awaits anyone found guilty of treason or 'setting fire to ships in Her Majesty's dockyards'.  I urge any female member of the Pierrepoint family to consider changing her surname by deed poll to Pierrettepointe so as to keep matters nicely dovetailed into the gender sensibilities of the OP. Gallows humor, anyone?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no established gender-neutral term for *hangman* (other than the more generic *executioner*).

For example, [Government of Canada](https://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/style/nonsexistguidelines-eng.html) offers comprehensive guidelines for gender-neutral language substitutes. But their guidelines do not consider the word *hangman*.

A Google Ngram search shows that *hangperson* is not in print. Even *hangwoman* is vanishingly rare. You can of course use these terms anyway, as you will undoubtedly be understood.

Comment: There are dozens of examples of "hangperson" or "hangpersons" in print, some of which I cited in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

### No gender-neutral alternative of the same specificity seems to be in common use

As indicated by the other comments and MetaEd's answer, there does not seem to be any well-established alternative term that would be unambiguously gender-neutral. (But as indicated by DavePhD's answer, the obvious alterations "hangwoman" and "hangperson" are attested in print, although you can see that in a number of the cited passages the author points out or implies that the word is not usual.)

### It is possible for "hangman" to be used to refer to a woman

The word "hangman" may actually be what is called an "exocentric" compound rather than an "endocentric" compound. "Exocentric" compounds are words like "cutthroat" where the compound as a whole refers to something that is different from either of the constituent words. A "cutthroat" is not a type of throat; it is a person who cuts throats. Likewise, "hangman" may in fact be etymologically "a person who hangs men" rather than "a man who hangs."

The argument for this etymological analysis can be found in Piotr Gąsiorowski's comments on the following Languagehat post: [Batman](http://languagehat.com/batman/).

> Piotr Gąsiorowski says:
>   
> November 24, 2014 at 4:26 pm
>   
> [...] *hangman* is, etymologically, a *pickpocket*-type exocentric compound in which the first member is a verb and the second member its object (cf. *spendthrift, cutthroat, scarecrow,* etc.); so a *hangman* is ‘one who hangs men (well, women too)’ rather than ‘a man who hangs (people)’.

> George Gibbard says:
>   
> November 25, 2014 at 1:16 am
>   
> Piotr — wait, how do you know that
>
> > a hangman is ‘one who hangs men (well, women too)’ rather than ‘a man who hangs (people)’
>
> I’m sure you have your reasons for saying this, I just want to know what they are.

> Piotr Gąsiorowski says:
>   
> November 25, 2014 at 4:46 am
>   
> George:
>
> 1. The non-existence of parallel formations: all other Early English nouns with *-man* as the second element have a noun (or sometimes an adjective), not a verb, as their first member. Even *ploughman* and *waccheman* ‘watchman’ are N+N, not V+N (like *ploughwrighte* and *waccheword*). We have *slaughterman* but no **slẹ̄man*; *horsman* but no **rīdeman*. The same goes for other endocentric compounds. *Hangglider* is possible today, when zero-derived nouns are indistinguishable from verb stems, but in ME *hang(e)man, hong(e)man, heng(e)man,* the first member is unambiguously a verb. Some counterexamples admittedly existed, e.g. ME *whetstǭn* (< OE *hwetstān*) ‘whetstone’, *grīndstǭn* and *rīdewei* ‘riding-path’, OE rīdehere ‘cavalry’ (beside more common *rǣdehere,* with *rǣde* ‘mounted’), but they seem to have been rare at the time, and I haven’t been able to found any among ME occupational terms.
> 2. The existence of exocentric parallels (*hangdog,* whose original meaning was ‘municipal dog-killer’ — a low-prestige profession, it seems).
> 3. The actual (if rare) attestation of the expected exocentric plural in Middle English (*hengmannis*).

It is true that this etymological information is unlikely to be known by modern English speakers. And in fact, modern speakers form the plural as "hangmen," which could be viewed as evidence that the correct synchronic morphological analysis of "hangman" is as an endocentric compound (for an overview of the arguments about whether irregular inflected forms really are reliable indicators of the grammatical structure of compound words, see this post from Language Log "[Systematic irregularization](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/004151.html)" that RegDwigнt♦ linked to in a comment beneath the following question: [Past participle of “fly”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56158/past-participle-of-fly?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

However, there are some other indications that the word may be gender-neutral:

- There are examples of the word "hangman" being used in past literature to refer to a woman. In the children's book *The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe,* the character Jadis, the "White Witch", is referred to as "[the Emperor's hangman](http://www.sparknotes.com/lit/lion/characters.html)".
- Even endocentric compounds ending in *-man* have often been considered to have some degree of gender-neutrality (although this usage is in decline).  The following note from dictionary.com confirms both of these points:

  > The use of *[-man](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/-man)* as the last element in compounds referring to a person of either sex who performs some function ( *anchorman; chairman; spokesman*) has declined a great deal in recent years.

Comment: A very nice answer to an undeserving question, the OP specifically asks: `I'm wondering if there's any suitable replacement.`

Comment: @Mari-LouA: Well, I think "no" is a valid answer (that MetaEd already gave, it's true), so I consider my answer to be on-topic. I switched the order of the sections to make the "no" answer clearer.

Comment: Even if _hangman_ is "a person who hangs men" it still lacks gender-neutrality as it excludes the possibility of hanging women. Anyway I think that sense of the word is unlikely, and even if true, unlikely to be accepted given the variety of other _-man_ words.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: It doesn't technically exclude the possibility of hanging women; it just doesn't explicitly state it. I think it in fact implies it, like a "man-eating tiger" is not implied to discriminate by gender in its anthropophagy.

Comment: By this analogy though, that tiger should just be called an "eatman".

Comment: You could have started with " 'Hangwoman' just sounds weird" and be done with it.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: The word "eatman" happens to not exist, but that would be an analogous construction, yes (if the quoted posts by Gąsiorowski are correct).

Comment: This is really interesting and sits well with the fact that in my childhood the letter-guessing game wasn't called 'hangman', but 'hang-a-man'.

Comment: "hangwoman" has been used since 1850 https://books.google.com/books?id=x9hmLRpZ9eAC&pg=PA104&dq=%22hangwoman%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwilnq_z_JzTAhVEVyYKHaIiBkMQ6AEINjAE#v=onepage&q=%22hangwoman%22&f=false

Comment: Women were not usually hanged I believe. Weren't they burnt instead?

Comment: @Deonyi: I don't know what was usual, but Tripehound's link demonstrates that at least some women were hanged: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/320758/is-hangman-a-gender-neutral-term/383762?noredirect=1#comment903101_320758

Comment: Ah, my bad. Burning was only for certain offences and was abolished by the end of the 18th century.

Answer (score 8):

**Hangperson** has been used.

The first use I see is an article titled [all too common hangperson](https://books.google.com/books?id=Eq7oAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hangperson%22&dq=%22hangperson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF2JSf3ZzTAhXCQSYKHdsHDQg4FBDoAQghMAA) *Library Association Record*, Volume 78 (1976).

Next is [The New Yorker](https://books.google.com/books?id=h9geAQAAMAAJ&q=%22hangperson%22&dq=%22hangperson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf69GO3ZzTAhXBSiYKHUd2BIM4ChDoAQhIMAk) Volume 58 (1982):

> Offscreen, Control Data has a computer game with the peculiar, if commendably nonsexist, name of Hangperson.

So apparently there was a videogame titled "Hangperson" that New York was praising for not being sexist.

Perhaps the same game is being reference by *Electronic Education*, Volume 2  (1983):

> After choosing a word category and selecting the options of English/Spanish, Spanish /English or mixed vocabulary, the student selects either a hangperson word guess game or a pyramid game. The student is given complete instruction on program use as s/he proceeds.
>
> The games are designed to challenge a student to succeed. Hangperson is the traditional guessing game

See also [The Addison-Wesley Book of Apple Software 1984](https://books.google.com/books?id=3vbXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hangperson%22&dq=%22hangperson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf69GO3ZzTAhXBSiYKHUd2BIM4ChDoAQglMAE)

Then there is a different computer game also titled "Hangperson" mentioned in [Science Software](https://books.google.com/books?id=9DnxAAAAMAAJ&q=%22hangperson%22&dq=%22hangperson%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjf69GO3ZzTAhXBSiYKHUd2BIM4ChDoAQg2MAU), Volume 4 (1988):

> *Hangperson*, a word game designed to foster familiarity with plant physiology terminology

Apart from computer games, [Scholars and Personal Computers: Microcomputing in the Human and Social Sciences](https://books.google.com/books?id=lp-QAAAAIAAJ&q=%22or%20hangman%22%20are%20flagged%20(substitute%20mailperson?%20hangperson?),%20as%20is%20a%20reference%20to%20a%20husband%20as%20%22he%22%20which%20is%20%5Bat%20least,%20so%20far%5D%20proper.&dq=%22or%20hangman%22%20are%20flagged%20(substitute%20mailperson?%20hangperson?),%20as%20is%20a%20reference%20to%20a%20husband%20as%20%22he%22%20which%20is%20%5Bat%20least,%20so%20far%5D%20proper.&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwia_9uU4ZzTAhUKySYKHduwB4AQ6AEIIjAA) (1988) seems to discuss computer software for detecting sexist language:

> Mailman or hangman" are flagged (substitute mailperson? hangperson?), as is a reference to a husband as "he" which is [at least, so far] proper.

There is also an article titled [The Hangpersons of Merdunique](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/aujls4&div=7&g_sent=1&collection=journals) *Australian Journal of Law and Society* (1987):

> a number of women from the village of Homme-sur-
>   Femme wrote to the Duke, asking whether the profession of hangman -
>   or, as they said, hangperson - could be opened to females.

> A group consisting of one hundred and fifty men and fifty women
>   replied that the occupation of hangperson became a man but not a
>   woman …

> A group of about a hundred women then wrote to the Duke,
>   supporting the women of Homme-sur-Femme and urging that men and
>   women be given equal access to all professions, including that of
>   hangperson. "Women should not be deprived", they wrote, "of an
>   opportunity to acquire any skill possessed by a man".

> After conferring long into the night with his Council, the Duke
>   issued a proclamation. It said that the Duke accepted the principle of
>   equal access to the skilled professions and that henceforward all posts in
>   those professions would be open equally to men and to women. It added,
>   however, that, since the profession of hangperson had been particularly at
>   issue, he was creating, as an interim measure, one hundred and fifty new
>   positions of hangperson, which would be open only to female applicants.

> One hundred and fifty women were appointed and took a six-month
>   training course, in which they became proficient in the skills of hanging,
>   drawing and quartering, as well as boiling in oil, beheading, strangling,
>   garrotting, cutting off of hands, noses and ears, and the gouging out of
>   eyes, not to mention flogging, flaying, racking and the use of
>   thumbscrews.

The article ["Guinea Pigs" and the Czech Novel "Under Padlock" in the 1970s: From the Modern Absolutism to the Postmodernist Absolute](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1347265?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) *Rocky Mountain Review of Language and Literature* vol. 37,(1983) says:

> a college for prospective "hangpersons" is established

[The Source of Apathy and Lack of Credibility](http://epublications.marquette.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1624&context=lnq&sei-redir=1&referer=http%3A%2F%2Fscholar.google.com%2Fscholar%3Fq%3D%2522hangpersons%2522%26btnG%3D%26hl%3Den%26as_sdt%3D1%252C47#search=%22hangpersons%22) *The Linacre Quarterly*: Vol. 55 (1988) says:

> physicians are the new hangmen. (Make that "hangpersons".)

[The Death Penalty as a Controversy over Social Values](http://heinonline.org/HOL/Page?handle=hein.journals/albany54&div=26&g_sent=1&collection=journals#) *Albany Law Review*, vol. 54 (1990):

> There are countries that refuse to extradite criminals who flee these shores; they will not deliver human beings to the American hangperson.

---

Alternatively, there is a gender-neutral term in the [Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia](http://www.micmap.org/dicfro/search/century-dictionary/hanger) (1889):

> **hanger**
>
> 2. One who hangs persons, or inflicts the penalty of hanging; a hangman

Similarly, [*A Dictionary of the English Language originally by Samuel Johnson*](https://books.google.com/books?id=2dMJOBI0xukC&pg=PT282&lpg=PT282&dq=%22%20was%20a%20very%20severe%20hanger%20of%20highwaymen%20%22&source=bl&ots=1XK4Q_pLdU&sig=S2QGJhnFvfD3sYirpi-EOZGESw8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj62satkJ3TAhXD0iYKHa9BAxsQ6AEIJzAC#v=onepage&q=%22%20was%20a%20very%20severe%20hanger%20of%20highwaymen%20%22&f=false), and edited by the Rev. H. J. Todd in 1827, second edition, vol. II says:

> HA'NGER One who causes others to be hanged

Comment: I agree if you really want a gender neutral term this would be it. Of course the opening line is loaded with connotations... Women never used to hang anyone when the poem was written. Do they even now?

Comment: @Gary "The Story of a Hangwoman" was published June 1883, long before that poem.  https://books.google.com/books?id=iToFAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA669&dq=%22hangwoman%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjVmrWj8ZzTAhUBRSYKHfAlCI0Q6AEITTAI#v=onepage&q=%22hangwoman%22&f=false

Comment: I stand corrected sir, bravo.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few obsolete terms that could be substituted, just for fun (none would be familiar enough nowadays to be clear to the general public). All citations/etymologies are from the *Oxford English Dictionary* (probably the only dictionary that preserves these very outdated terms, but unfortunately behind a pay-wall):

> **boie, *n.*** Obs. rare. An executioner, hangman.

Etymology is unclear, but may come from "Old French *buie, boye* fetter, chain." Latest attestation way back in c.1320.

> **derrick, *n.*** †1. A hangman; hanging; the gallows.

Apparently derives from the surname of an actual c.1600 Tyburn hangman. This meaning is preserved to some extent in *oil derricks* and the like, which are hoisting mechanisms. Apparently the term went from being used for the hangman, to being used for the gallows, to being used for any similar structure. A gruesome etymology to consider for anyone using such a machine! Last citation in the OED meaning *hangman* is in mid-17th century.

> **ketch, *n.*** The hangman.

Also derived from the name of a notorious hangman, in this case *Jack Ketch*. The full name was still in current use as a slang term for a hangman at the turn of the 20th century, when this particular OED entry was created, but I think the shorter version fits better with the gender-neutral requirement.

Incidentally, I note that the OED has an entry for *hang-woman*, with two attestations from the 1880s (one hyphenated and one compound).

Finally, if novel words are of interest to anyone reading this post (I presume the OP's interest has been satisfied), I would propose *hangster* as somewhat more felicitous-while-simultaneously-ominous (due to the rhyme with *gangster*) than *hangperson*. The -ster ending is productive in English, and has a curious history with regard to gender: it was originally a *feminine* ending but transitioned to gender-neutral and then somewhat masculine, and today is again mostly neutral in usage (e.g. *hipsters* can be either male or female).

Answer (score 2):

To add to other responses, I agree that the gender-neutral word would fit well as *hanger* if *hangman* is too gender-specific.

I'm surprised that *hangestere* was not mentioned in any comment or answer, however.

> **Hangman**: public executioner, mid-14c. (mid-13c. as a surname), from *hang* (v.) + *man* (n.). As the name of a spelling game, by 1951. ***Hangestere* "female executioner" is found mid-15c.** [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=hangman&allowed_in_frame=0)

Although, granted, it seems to have lived and died in Middle English.

Middle English dictionary [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=72391107&egdisplay=compact&egs=72391623) says:

> **hangestere** (n.) - A female executioner.
>
> c1450 Pilgr.LM (Cmb Ff.5.30)   144:  '*At the laste j wole hange hem my self as j haue hanged many an oother.' 'Now,' quod j, 'art thow an **hangestere**?' 'Ye, certeyn,' quod she*.

So, given the word *hangestere*'s existence and *hangman*'s perceived gender, it seems that *hanger* is related but decidedly neutral in today's English. And perhaps most importantly, it will be understood.

Comment: "hangster", mentioned by 1006a, is I believe a modernized version of "hangestere"

Comment: @sumelic, yes, you're right- either *hanger* or *hangster* would function well as a modern gender-neutral word for *hangman*. My only concern is that *hangster* is not as well-known.... Googling it brings up primarily social media applications and companies (evidently it's being taken as "one who hangs out with others", rather than "one who hangs others"), or other more slang meanings of variations of *gangster* (like 1006a mentioned, to be fair). *Hanger* has more of a background and usage in the definition desired. But hey, if people start using *hangster*, great!! :)

Comment: Oh, excellent, there's that feminine -ster(e) ending! I saw that social media thing, too; if it catches on, I'll probably always associate it with executions now. I think the main drawback to *hanger* is that it's the word, at least in the US, for the mundane things you hang your clothes on.