# Is a software loop “breaked” or “broken”?

Tags: word-choice, past-tense, programming, irregular-verbs

In software development there are code loop constructions, which you can BREAK.

```
foreach(i in integers)
  ...
  break
```

If I break the cycle, it becomes *broken* or *breaked*?

Which sentence is correct in this context: *loop is broken* or *loop is breaked*? It is important to distinguish between *broken* as incorrect one and *broken* as interrupted.

Comment: Just anecdotal evidence, but in decades of programming C-like languages, I've never used or seen "breaked".

Comment: I wouldn't say you have broken the loop, but that you have broken *out* of the loop. This disambiguates it from the other sense of broken.

Comment: We’d normally use *exited* or *terminated*, rather than a past tense of *break*.

Comment: Program execution tend to be described dynamically. A 'break' statement is a command with results. The past participle that usually attends the 'break' statement is 'interrupted': "The for loop _was_ interrupted by the break statement". 'Broken' is a static thing. "The for loop _is_ broken because of the syntax error"

Comment: To echo JonLarby and Lawrence, because programmers otherwise describe _code as broken_ (meaning: not working) you'd tend to use _broken out of_ or _exited_ (the loop).

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. Do any dictionaries use the traditionally unacceptable past simple 'breaked' in this sense?

Comment: @All It is insufficient to give an answer here giving an unsupported '_breaked_ is wrong'. The answers to the question [When and why is 'flied' used as the past tense of 'fly'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31134/when-and-why-is-flied-used-as-the-past-tense-of-fly) show that regularisation of irregular verbs is not unknown.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on a programming site, as the question is specific to that domain. in that rather isolated domain, otherwise irregular words such as 'breaked' might prove acceptable.

Comment: I can not ask grammar questions on stackoverflow

Comment: Clarity in explaining algorithms is one of the more pressing issues of our time. My vote is to keep this question open, and to encourage more like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to describe a computer program depends on the level you want to speak at, e.g.

- The result is **found**.
- The iteration **terminates**.
- The loop is **exited**.
- The interpreter **executes the break statement**.
- The processor **branches**, and so on.

The problem with words like *break* is that they aren’t strongly associated with any particular level, and they have larger meanings, e.g. a broken loop can be one that does not implement the programmer’s original intention. However, the designer of a programming language naturally wants to use words that have meaning to humans, and sometimes this can be misleading. When, for example, was the last time you saw a *print* statement causing something to appear on a physical printer?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is better to correct wording and make the loop "cancelled" or "interrrupted"

Comment: In choosing words to describe a computer program, it’s worth remembering that all automated processes can be modeled as finite state machines. Sometimes, you want to talk about the state transition in terms of structures. At other times, you want to talk about how the program moves through a sequence of states. IMHO, terms like *loop* pose a challenge, since it’s a structural term (a noun) that can also be used as a verb to describe an action, i.e. *looping*. So when you use it, you can slip from one mode of description to another, and therefore find the next word hard to think of.

Answer (score 0):

Break is an irregular verb, so we have break - broke (past) - broken (past participle)

P.S. I've never heard or seen "breaked" ). But you can try to use this word as a joke ("savvy" - Jack Sparrow)

Comment: But does this answer for the context of the OP?